# How to catch an output of command executed with WinSCP .NET assembly using Session.ExecuteCommand

Tags: c#, ssh, winscp, winscp-net

```
(...)
Session sess = new Session();
sess.Open(sessionParams);
(...)
sess.ExecuteCommand('/home/kit/count.sh').Check();
```

Using WinSCP .NET assembly I create a connection to my Linux host and execute a script. My problem is to catch result of script to C# variable. In this case is just a single string. I've found a properties of session object called output but I am really do not know how to use it.

Would you help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Session.ExecuteCommand` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_executecommand) returns an instance of [`CommandExecutionResult`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_commandexecutionresult).

The `CommandExecutionResult` has a property `Output`.

```
CommandExecutionResult result = sess.ExecuteCommand('/home/kit/count.sh');
result.Check();
string output = result.Output;
```